# Using Metropolis code analysis tool for React applications

Tags: visualization, code-analysis

Has anyone tried using Metropolis https://www.npmjs.com/package/metropolis code analysis tool with React/ES6 application ?

I am trying to get the code analyse my ES6 code which uses React. It fails without giving me correct logs and hence not able to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube and or which scanner do you use? Which logs do you get (even if they are not the *correct logs*)?

Comment: Btw: If you are only interested in a visual representation of your code, check out http://softvis3d.com/#/try